# Stop YouTube API Autoplay

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, autoplay

I have a video player on my website made up of codes held in a database, and I'd like it to stop playing the first video on autoplay. What code is needed and where does it go?

The code I currently use is:

```
var $vid1 = <?php echo json_encode($code_1); ?>;
var $vid2 = <?php echo json_encode($code_2); ?>;
var $vid3 = <?php echo json_encode($code_3); ?>;
var $vid4 = <?php echo json_encode($code_4); ?>;
var $vid5 = <?php echo json_encode($code_5); ?>;
var $vid6 = <?php echo json_encode($code_6); ?>;
var $vid7 = <?php echo json_encode($code_7); ?>;
var $vid8 = <?php echo json_encode($code_8); ?>;
var videoIDs = [
    $vid1,
    $vid2,
    $vid3,
    $vid4,
    $vid5,
    $vid6,
    $vid7,
    $vid8
];

var player, currentVideoId = 0;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '248',
        width: '440',
        playerVars: {
            autoplay: 0
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        currentVideoId++;
        if (currentVideoId < videoIDs.length) {
            player.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
        }
    }
}

function next(){
    currentVideoId++;
    if (currentVideoId < videoIDs.length) {
            player.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
    }
}

function previous(){
    currentVideoId--;
    if (currentVideoId >= 0) {
            player.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
    }
    else currentVideoId = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a parameter **autoplay:0** to add inside *new YT.player()* parameters.

More details here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autoplay

Comment: Thanks. I've added that but it still autoplays. Is there something else in my code further down overriding it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a parameter you can supply to stop videos auto playing.  You just need to add this to your existing code...

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '248',
        width: '440',
        playerVars: {
            autoplay: 0
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
```

You can find more info on the playerVars options here...

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5

Comment: Thanks Archer. I've added that, but it's still autoplaying the first video?

Comment: Shouldn't it be set to 0/Non-Autoplay by default? Is something else in my code affecting the autoplay?

Comment: Is your site online?  I could have a look if it is.

Comment: It's actually in the final stages of development and was going online today, but this issue needed sorting before I added it. Basically this is the only Javascript I have on the page, and the rest of the code after this is basic HTML4.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include All of the Javascript for this video player!

Comment: I can't see any reason why it would play.  Sorry.

Comment: Seems a bit odd that it would Autoplay by default anyway. Looks like I'll have to grin and bear it until I come across a full solution. Thanks anyway Archer